# Passing complex parameters to a Nimrod macro

Tags: macros, compile-time, nim-lang

I would like to pass configuration parameters to a macro. I already have a procedure that produce a string of Nimrod code based on these parameters (a tuple of sequences).
I know that I can pass a string and convert it with [strVal](http://nim-lang.org/macros.html#strVal) (as shown the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/19956317/334703). Can I do the same with more complex data?

Alternatively can I use this string of Nimrod code in a compile-time procedure with a call to a procedure such as [parseStmt](http://nim-lang.org/macros.html#parseStmt)?

EDIT:
The generation of Nimrod code was useful to test my ideas bit I agree I should probably generate AST directly.

Here is an example of the structure I'm thinking about.

```
type
  Tconfig = tuple
    letters: seq[string]
    numbers:seq[int]

var
  data = (@("aa", "bb"), @(11, 22))

macro mymacro(data: Tconfig): stmt =
   ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need or want to traverse the structure of the data in the macro, first you need to make the variable a `const`. `var` are for runtime, so the macro will just get a `nnkSym` node. Once you make that a `const` you get the same input as if you had typed yourself the value manually there. I'll use the `treeRepr` macro and plenty of `echo` to show you what kind of AST you get and how you would walk it:

```
import macros

type
  Tconfig = tuple
    letters: seq[string]
    numbers:seq[int]

const data: Tconfig = (@["aa", "bb"], @[11, 22])

macro mymacro(data: Tconfig): stmt =
  echo "AST being passed in:\n", treeRepr(data)
  echo "root type is ", data.kind
  echo "number of children ", len(data)
  let n1 = data[0]
  echo "first child is ", n1.kind
  echo "first child children ", len(n1)
  let e2 = n1[1]
  echo "second exp child is ", e2.kind
  echo "second exp child children ", len(e2)
  let v1 = e2[0]
  echo "first seq value is ", v1.kind
  echo "first seq value children ", len(v1)
  echo "Final literal is ", v1.strVal

when isMainModule:
  mymacro(data)
```

When I compile that example I get the following output:

```
AST being passed in:
Par
  ExprColonExpr
    Sym "letters"
    Bracket
      StrLit aa
      StrLit bb
  ExprColonExpr
    Sym "numbers"
    Bracket
      IntLit 11
      IntLit 22
root type is nnkPar
number of children 2
first child is nnkExprColonExpr
first child children 2
second exp child is nnkBracket
second exp child children 2
first seq value is nnkStrLit
first seq value children 0
Final literal is aa
```

Comment: Thank you a lot. The example is really useful.

Answer (score 2):

if your macro needs to process the actual constant data passed to it, the recommended way is to use static params:

```
type
  TConfig = tuple
    letters: seq[string]
    numbers:seq[int]

const data = (@["aa", "bb"], @[11, 22])

macro mymacro(cfg: static[TConfig]): stmt =
  echo "letters"
  for s in cfg.letters:
    echo s

  echo "numbers"
  for n in cfg.numbers:
    echo n

mymacro(data)
```

This approach have multiple benefits:

1) Instead of getting a raw AST, the input param `cfg` will have the `TConfig` type inside the macro body, so you can more easily access its members as shown in the example.

2) The compiler will automatically evaluate complex expressions that produce `TConfig` values, when they are used with the macro (e.g. `mymacro(mergeConfigs(userConfig, systemConfig))`, assuming that `mergeConfigs` is some proc that could be evaluated at compile-time).

For more information regarding static params, please refer to the manual: 
http://nim-lang.org/manual.html#static-t

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% certain what you mean, but from the context, it looks as though the functionality you need is that of `macros.toStrLit`, which generates a string literal node from an AST. Example:

```
import macros, strutils

macro showExpr(x: expr): stmt =
  parseStmt("echo(" & x.toStrLit.strVal.escape & ")")

showExpr("x" & "y")
```

Consider transforming the AST directly, though, because generating and reparsing code as strings can lead to surprises with quoting (note the `.escape` above), indentation, etc.

Comment: Thank you for these first information. I've edited the question to try to be clearer.